# RAM usage when working with large files with rioxarray

Tags: rasterio, rioxarray

I am currently working with a large file in rioxarray.

The File I want to write has the dimension 47, 24464, 23363, using the datatype uint8. Results into RAM usage of minimum 25 GB. Which I never would have noticed without the problem because the file on disk will be smaller than 50 MB (due to compression).

To be able to save every of the 47 layers of the raster file with it's own name, I use xarray's Dataset as data structure.

```py
for i, x in enumerate(tqdm(list(files))):
  v = open_rasterio(x)
  k = x.stem.split('_', 1)[1] if len(x.stem.split('_')) > 2 else 'Classification'

  d_set[k] = v.squeeze()
d_set.rio.to_raster(save_path, compress='zstd', zstd_level=1, num_threads='all_cpus', tiled=True, dtype='uint8, driver="GTiff", predictor=2)
```

the first problem I encountered is: while the RAM is enough to hold the dataset, it's often not enough to save it. It seems to create a second numpy array, that holds the same data!
Therefore, traditional methods to reduce RAM usage, does not work.

1. There is no smaller datatype
2. The data attribute, does not work with packed arrays, or with sparse arrays.

So after deinstalling every program, that was not needed it sometimes worked.

Are there some (other) solutions? The documentation  also hints that disk is usable. Could that help, how?  Can the file be written in increments? -> Append it on disk with every incrementation in the loop? Why is the extra numpy array needed?

Answer (score 0):

When opening, set `cache=False` and when writing, set `windowed=True` for reading/writing large files:

```py
xds = open_rasterio(filename, cache=False)
xds.rio.to_raster(save_path, compress='zstd', zstd_level=1, num_threads='all_cpus', tiled=True, dtype='uint8', driver="GTiff", predictor=2, windowed=True)
```

- https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/rioxarray.html#rioxarray-open-rasterio
- https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/rioxarray.html#rioxarray.raster_array.RasterArray.to_raster

For the second part, see: https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/issues/296